# Strange FFT spectrum after resampling

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum

I'm pretty new to signal processing and have encountered strange behaviour.

I have a vibration signal from a non-stationary gearbox component that I need to resample to do order analysis. The original sampling frequency is 25.6kHz. It seems to be working fine for most signals but one output looks weird.

The image below shows what the FFT transformation of a signal should look like. 
[image: Correct FFT transformation]

This image shows the weird transformed signal.

[image: Incorrect FFT transformation]

Although the FFT looks similar, the axis are wrong. Does anybody know what could cause this? All help appreciated!

Comment: You need to tell us how the re sampling was done and the graph produced. Seems like a tool or pilot error. Even your first graph doesn't make a lot of sense. If you sample at 25.6kHz you should have little or no energy above 12 kHz.

Comment: No that would not make any sense. The plots shown are created with a sample rate of about 36.6kHz

Comment: If this was re-sampled from 25.6kHz to 36.6kHz, the re-sampler did a really poor job and created lots of aliasing.

Comment: Same problem but different question (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/64816/upsampling-question-aliasing-imaging-problem)